# Commiting the failed transaction again

Tags: java, hibernate

I have some database operation present inside the transaction. I am setting the entity objects and tried to save them using session.merge(object). But due to some constraint transaction is failing. I have provided a exception handler in which i am setting the same object once again and tried to commit it. My question is that after the failed transaction whether the values which i have set earlier will still be there in the object or not.

Comment: Why don't you try it already? From what I understand, the object will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason that a transaction rollback would change the state of an entity. The whole idea of rollback is to reset the system to the last state before the transaction was started.

Comment: what I wanted to ask is that i m not rolling back the transaction once it is failed. So without rolling back the object will remain intact with the values which were set before the transaction was failed ??

Comment: ? AFAIK, a transaction is always rolled back once it failed. That's why we do transactions. It's all or nothing (= rollback)